# Running python tweepy listener

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy

I have a python script that scans for new tweets containing specified #hashtags, then it posts them to my "python bot's" twitter account as new tweets.

I tested it from the python console and let it run for 5 minutes. It managed to pick up 10 tweets matching my criteria. It works flawlessly, but I'm concerned about performance issues and leaving the script running for extended amounts of time.

- What are the negative effects of leaving this script running on my personal computer for a whole day or more?
- Should I be running this on a digital ocean VPS instead?
- Twitter offers the API for bot creation, but do they care how much a bot tweets? I don't see how this is any different from retweeting.

Comment: Thank you for downvoting and requesting to close this question without leaving a comment. I would be more than happy to post this on the proper forum if pointed in the right direction. I commend your ability downvote at light speed.

Comment: Im not sure if twitter cares about how much a  bot reads unless you are posting( or spamming) with 100s of tweets per minute. As far as the negative aspects are concerned , I would never suggest you to run a script for a whole day on a personal computer. More so, if you are storing any kind of data which has the ability to just blow up take up a lot of space

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twitter probably has limits on their api and will most likely block your api key if they feel that you are spamming. In fact I would bet there is a maximum number of tweets per day depending on the type of developer account.

For stability and up time concerns running on a 'personal' computer is not a good idea. You probably want to do other things on your personal comp that may interrupt your bot's service (like install programs/updates and restart). As far as load on the cpu, well if its only picking up 10 tweets per 5 min that doesn't seem like any kind of load that you need to worry about. To be sure you could run the `top` command and check out the cpu and memory usage.

If you have a server somewhere like at digital ocean then I would run it there just to reduce the interruption the program experiences.

I ran a similar program using twitters stream api and collected tweets using a personal computer and the interruptions were annoying and I eventually stopped collecting data....